# Problems with bash, source and if statements not working as I want

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a configure file for a script that generates a website.

I got this code in my script.sh to generate the website:

```
#!/bin/bash
. ./configTest.sh --source-only
chosenFunction()
{
    if [ "$func" = 1 ] ; then
{
        cat <<- _EOF_
            <html>
            <p> Code to call the chosen function </p>
            </html>
        _EOF_
}
else
{
        cat <<- _EOF_
            <html>
            <p> Code to call the chosen function </p>
            </html>
        _EOF_
}
fi

gen_page()
{
    cat <<- _EOF_
    <html>
    <p>$(chosenFunction)</p>
    </html>
    _EOF_
}
gen_page() >> website.html
```

In my config file I got this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

func=
changeFunction()
{
echo "
Config function

Which function?

1 - function1
2 - function2
"
echo -n "   Enter selection: "
read select
echo ""

case $select in

    1 ) 
    clear
    func=1
    echo "  function1 is set
    "
    ;;
    2 )
    clear
    func=2
    echo "  function 2 is set
    "
    ;;
    * ) clear; echo "Please enter a valid option"
esac    
}
main()
{
    clear
    changeFunction
}

if [ "${1}" != "--source-only" ]; then
    main "${@}"
fi
```

For some reason this script doesn't change the value of the `function` variable so the website always displays `function1`. 
The config script always output the menu twice which I don't understand either.

- Updated the script as @ruakh suggested but now the problem is it always uses the `else` part of the `if statement`so I can never change between the two html code segments the way I desire

Comment: sounds like a scope issue

Comment: @PaulBastide care to elaborate? I'm very new with bash

Comment: don't you have to return the variable? and set function?  well based on http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html  you'd have to call it local to use a scope... change function to fun, and see if it works, function might be reserved

Comment: @PaulBastide I only used `function` in the example here to try and make it easy to understand so that is not the problem but I will change it to avoid confusion.

Comment: The generated HTML is not compliant to any HTML standard. However, we'll assume it got stripped to make a manageable question.

Comment: Yes, the HTML code was stripped down

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems with your code, but I think the one you're asking about is this: `[ function=1 ]` does not actually examine your `$function` variable. It just checks to see if the string `'function=1'` is non-empty; and it *is*, so it always evaluates to success (true). What you want is:

```
if [ "$function" = 1 ] ; then
```

(Note the spaces around `=`, so that you're passing three separate arguments to `[ ... ]`. When you only pass it one argument, it just tests it for non-emptiness.)

Comment: This works to change it but for some reason I can't change it back

Comment: So now the website always generates the code in the `else` statement and it's not possible to change back even the though `"$func" = 1`

Comment: @Benji: Have you tried inserting an `echo "'$func'"` to confirm that the value of `$func` is what you think it is?